# Remove set of string from a string, multiple occurences

Tags: regex

Want to completely remove any part of my string that has

`\"AddedDate\":\"\\/Date(1480542000000-0600)\\/\"`

The `1480526460000-0600` is not hardcoded, it could be any set of numbers (JSON dates).

Comment: `s/\"AddedDate\":\"\\/Date\([0-9]+-[0-9]+\)\\\?\"//g`

Comment: @eddiem seems legit! if you want to make it an answer I'll upvote and check it for you.

Comment: Use `jq` for json data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex [`\"AddedDate\":\"\\\/Date\(\d+(?:-\d+)?\)\\\?\"`](https://regex101.com/r/HXLy4N/6) and replace with empty string. If the regex engine doesn't support `\d`, replace them with `[0-9]`. This will match date format like `x` or `x-x`, x being any number of digits.

If you want to match exactly 13 numbers in the first part of the date and 4 in the second, use `\"AddedDate\":\"\\\/Date\(\d{13}(?:-\d{4})?\)\\\?\"`

**EDIT:** For new format use `\\\"AddedDate\\\":\\\"\\\\\/Date\(\d+(?:-\d+)?\)\\\\\/\\\"` it should work.

Comment: I see how this works in your example, but it's not working in my code. Here's a more updated string, which I did not include in my original post. `\"AddedDate\":\"\\/Date(1480542000000-0600)\\/\"` I tried to change some of your stuff on the example with no prevail, any insight?

Comment: That string has a different format than the string in your original post.  If there are certain characters that can be different, that's an important detail to know for constructing an appropriate regular expression.  It's also important to know whether any of these characters are being escaped.  The literal string pattern is what is needed to construct the regex.

Comment: Yes, my bad on that. The string I see when I debug is sometimes different then the string I see when I log. I noticed this difference after testing some of the regex provided here.

Comment: Do you want to match both formats or just this one?

Comment: just the new one i provided, again my apologies.

Comment: And yes any `backslash` that you see before a `"` is an escape sequence.

Comment: Can you edit the question to reflect an accurate representation of the string(s) you want to match, without escape characters?

Comment: See updated answer. Don't forget to upvote and accept ;)